# Why is Call Of Duty Modern Warfare 2 failing to install?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I purchased Call Of Duty Modern Warfare 2 from local retail shop, the game is brand new and never used.

I started installing it on my PC, after i inserted the DISC 1 it launched the steam service application and installation process started.

When I enter the KEY its associated successfully with my account and its valid.

The problem starts when I hit the next button and it just outputs a message that it can't install the game. I tried Offline Mode and yet the steam client suggests to switch to Online mode and proceeding with installing.

The same problem occurs every time I attempt installation, the game doesn't appear installed in my PC or in any folder in my disc.

I tried copying disc contents to my local disc and attempt to restore from within steam client but the same thing happened.

Also tried to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -install D:` still the same failure.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What exactly is the message that is displayed?  Also, did you try just redeeming the Key in Steam?  That could be an option, granted it will mean downloading the entire game.